# TypeScript Call Signature Error Only When Setting Value Twice

Tags: html, typescript

I am trying to change the value of an HTML input based upon if a checkbox is checked. It works totally fine if I only reset one input, but if I try to reset two inputs at the same time I get the error

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'String' has no compatible call signatures.
```

My code is as follows

```
 if((<HTMLInputElement>unavailableInputs[i]).checked){
                (<HTMLInputElement>qtyShippedInputs[i]).value = ""

                (<HTMLInputElement>trackingNumberInputs[i]).value = ""
            }
```

If I only reset one of the values, regardless of which one, it throws no errors and works totally fine. As soon as I do both qtyShipped and trackingNumber I get the error. In addition in the browser I get the error

```
"" is not a function
```

I appreciate any and all help.

As requested here is the whole code with a work around that solves the problem

```js
disableFulfillment(shipment) {
        const unavailableInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('unavailable-qty')
        const qtyShippedInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('qty-shipped')
        const requestedQtyFields = document.getElementsByClassName('requested-qty')
        const trackingNumberInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('tracking-number')
        const reasonCodeInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('reason-codes')
        const reasonCodeValues = []
        const lines = []
        const lineCompleted = []
        let i
        for (i = 0; i < trackingNumberInputs.length; i++) {
            if ((<HTMLInputElement>unavailableInputs[i]).checked) {
                (<HTMLInputElement>qtyShippedInputs[i]).value = ''
            }
            if ((<HTMLInputElement>unavailableInputs[i]).checked) {
                (<HTMLInputElement>trackingNumberInputs[i]).value = ''
            }

            if (!(<HTMLInputElement>unavailableInputs[i]).checked) {
                if ((<HTMLInputElement>unavailableInputs[i]).nextElementSibling) {
                    (<HTMLInputElement>unavailableInputs[i].nextElementSibling.firstChild).value = ''
                    reasonCodeValues[i] = (<HTMLInputElement>reasonCodeInputs[i]).value
                } else {
                    reasonCodeValues[i] = 0
                }
            } else {
                if ((<HTMLInputElement>unavailableInputs[i]).nextElementSibling.firstElementChild) {
                    reasonCodeValues[i] = (<HTMLInputElement>unavailableInputs[i].nextElementSibling.firstElementChild).value
                } else {
                    reasonCodeValues[i] = 0
                }
            }
         
            const inputs = {
                unavailable: (<HTMLInputElement>unavailableInputs[i]).checked,
                qtyShipped: (<HTMLInputElement>qtyShippedInputs[i]).value,
                requestedQty: (<HTMLInputElement>requestedQtyFields[i]).innerText,
                reasonCodeInputs: reasonCodeValues[i],
                trackingNumber: (<HTMLInputElement>trackingNumberInputs[i]).value
            }
            lines.push(inputs)
        }

        lines.forEach(line => {
            if (line.unavailable === true && (line.reasonCodeInputs === 'CUSTOMERCANCEL' || line.reasonCodeInputs === 'UNAVAILABLE')) {
                lineCompleted.push(true)
            } else if (line.qtyShipped === line.requestedQty && line.trackingNumber.length >= 9) {
                lineCompleted.push(true)
            } else {
                lineCompleted.push(false)
            }
        })

        return !lineCompleted.every(function(e) {
            return e === true
        })
    }
```

You will see the only change is that it is broken into two identical if statements. Which works no problem.

Here is the same code with the two setters placed inside the same if statement which breaks.

```js
disableFulfillment(shipment) {
        const unavailableInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('unavailable-qty')
        const qtyShippedInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('qty-shipped')
        const requestedQtyFields = document.getElementsByClassName('requested-qty')
        const trackingNumberInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('tracking-number')
        const reasonCodeInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('reason-codes')
        const reasonCodeValues = []
        const lines = []
        const lineCompleted = []
        let i
        for (i = 0; i < trackingNumberInputs.length; i++) {
            if ((<HTMLInputElement>unavailableInputs[i]).checked) {
                (<HTMLInputElement>qtyShippedInputs[i]).value = ''
                (<HTMLInputElement>trackingNumberInputs[i]).value = ''
            }
                


            if (!(<HTMLInputElement>unavailableInputs[i]).checked) {
                if ((<HTMLInputElement>unavailableInputs[i]).nextElementSibling) {
                    (<HTMLInputElement>unavailableInputs[i].nextElementSibling.firstChild).value = ''
                    reasonCodeValues[i] = (<HTMLInputElement>reasonCodeInputs[i]).value
                } else {
                    reasonCodeValues[i] = 0
                }
            } else {
                if ((<HTMLInputElement>unavailableInputs[i]).nextElementSibling.firstElementChild) {
                    reasonCodeValues[i] = (<HTMLInputElement>unavailableInputs[i].nextElementSibling.firstElementChild).value
                } else {
                    reasonCodeValues[i] = 0
                }
            }
         
            const inputs = {
                unavailable: (<HTMLInputElement>unavailableInputs[i]).checked,
                qtyShipped: (<HTMLInputElement>qtyShippedInputs[i]).value,
                requestedQty: (<HTMLInputElement>requestedQtyFields[i]).innerText,
                reasonCodeInputs: reasonCodeValues[i],
                trackingNumber: (<HTMLInputElement>trackingNumberInputs[i]).value
            }
            lines.push(inputs)
        }

        lines.forEach(line => {
            if (line.unavailable === true && (line.reasonCodeInputs === 'CUSTOMERCANCEL' || line.reasonCodeInputs === 'UNAVAILABLE')) {
                lineCompleted.push(true)
            } else if (line.qtyShipped === line.requestedQty && line.trackingNumber.length >= 9) {
                lineCompleted.push(true)
            } else {
                lineCompleted.push(false)
            }
        })

        return !lineCompleted.every(function(e) {
            return e === true
        })
    }
```

Comment: I see an `i` here involved. Is this inside a loop? If so, how do you determine from where to where the `i` is going to take values? Does `qtyShippedInputs` have the same lenght as `trackingNumberInputs` ? Are not any other operation involved here that might be causing the issue? I wonder.

Comment: There is a for loop involved. In fact  if I break it out into two identical if statements with setting the value in its own if statement it works without issue. It only throws the error if I set both of them inside one if statement.

Comment: It would be good if you post the code with the `for` too, since the problem seems to be there. I think you're accessing one of the arrays with an  improper index.

Comment: I can post it, but I am sure that is not the problem. Because the if statement is inside of the for loop. If I place it into two if statements that check the exact same conditional, but each if statement only changes one of the values it works. For some reason it only breaks if I place both of the setters inside an if statement. If they are broken out into two different if statement no problem.